# Differentiate between Sharepoint User defined columns and default columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007. How do I differentiate a user created column (the column that a user creates on his own for a SPList) from the columns that are available by default? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no practical way to do this. It may help if we know the reason you need to know the difference.

Comment: I need to get the user defined properties alone. When i iterate through SPList.Fields it gives me all the fields. I need to modify the values of user defined fields alone. Not all the fields.

Comment: Hi. I use SPField.SourceId property to differentiate between user defined fields and internal fields. It works for now. Will this be a foolproof way?

Comment: Hi, Did you get this working with SPField.SourceId property? Thanks

Comment: Yes. I got this working. But still not sure if this would hold good always.

Comment: This answer also might be useful: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-an-spfield-was-created-by-a-user

Answer (score 2):

SourceId is not foolproof. The Microsoft fields put a Microsoft namespace in it. Ones created in the GUI put a web GUID in it (or a list GUID). But ones created via code in third-party or custom solutions may put anything in there -- namespace or GUID.